# ES5 vs ES6 Javascript for Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, es5-shim

I am trying to convert the following to work, but I think it is an Es5/ES6 issue. Help Appreciated.

```
this.rows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.subCategoryModels.length / 3)).keys());
```

I currently get typscript errors:

```
[ts] 
Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'.
any
```

and

```
[ts] 
Property 'keys' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
any
```

Comment: maybe https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8174 is relevant

Comment: *"I think it is an Es5/ES6 issue"* - Are you trying to write for ES5 or ES6? Both `Array.from()` and `.keys()` are ES6 methods, so obviously they won't work in ES5.

Comment: try to insert 'new' like: "Array.from( new Array(Math..." and see if that helps.

Comment: I try the following, but I still get the same errors. `this.rows = Array.from(new Array(Math.ceil(this.subCategoryModels.length / 3)).keys());`

Comment: This works, but I don't think it is as elegant.        `for (var index = 0; index < Math.ceil(this.subCategoryModels.length / 3); index++) {
        this.rows.push(index);
      }`

Answer (score 1):

> Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'.

This points to the fact that you want to use `ES6` type definitions while still compiling to ES5.

Recommend the `lib` option in TypeScript latest:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
}
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#lib-option

Answer (score 0):

Since you're seeing these errors, I'm assuming you're compiling to ES5. You can use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) to make Typescript recognize the es2015 functions for arrays.

First, install [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) if not already installed.

`npm install typings --global`

Once you've installed typings, install type type definitions for ES2015 array functions.

`typings install -SG env~es2015-array`

If you're targeting a browser that does not support the new Array functions, you'll also need to add a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

**html**

```
  <ion-row *ngFor="let trio of getTriples()">
    <ion-col *ngFor="let item of trio" (click)="itemTapped(item)">
      <div class="row responsive-md">
        <div id="icon-image-{{item.id}}"><img src="data:image/png;base64,{{item.icon}}" height="75" width="75" /></div>
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

**typescript**

```
  getTriples() {
    let triples = [];
    let length = this.subCategoryModels.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
      let trio = [];
      trio.push(this.subCategoryModels[i]);
      if (i + 1 < length) {
        trio.push(this.subCategoryModels[i + 1]);
      }
      if (i + 2 < length) {
        trio.push(this.subCategoryModels[i + 2]);
      }
      triples.push(trio);
    }
    return triples;
  }
```